# \textrm: compilation error in math mode

Tags: errors

After a large amount of time looking at the screen I couldn't find what is the source of error. Here is a **minimal code**:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{multimedia}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Estrategias de cálculo}

Puede escribirse:

$\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{neto}} = \Delta G_{\textrm{r}}^\circ{(\textrm{AH})} + \Delta G_{\textrm{r}}^\circ{(\textrm{B^-})}$

Se calcula $\Delta G^\circ_{\textrm{neto}}$ y se despeja $\Delta G_{\textrm{r}}^\circ{(\textrm{AH})}$ . El valor restante se toma de cálculos o experimental.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

```
  ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\textdef@ ...h {#1}\let \f@size #2\selectfont #3}}
l.29 \end{frame}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

Do you see anything wrong in the mathematical formulae?

Comment: Have you tried deleting all aux files and then recompiling from scratch?

Comment: The MWE was compiled for first time and produce the error..@Mico

Comment: move this `^-` from `(\textrm{B^-})` to `(\textrm{B}^-)`.

Comment: :O  howwwwww??@CroCo thanks!

Comment: `^` has meaning in the math mode. You can't add it the way you did.

Comment: @CroCo if you want answer the question/problem or I can remove it..(thanks again)

Comment: You can just rename it to "\textrm and compilation error"... This way someone could find it useful.

Comment: right, I will do that @koleygr

Comment: Nice!... enough clear title and solution.

Comment: Note that the error message you quote comes from removing `biblatex` in the preamble. There are still a few remnants of `biblatex`'s commands holding out in the `.aux` file that are now that `biblatex` is not loaded undefined. If you delete the `.aux` file and recompile, the error about `\abx@aux@sortscheme` will be gone. Of course you will still get the other error, but the one from your question will be gone (it's a bit confusing because it is not reproduced by running the MWE exactly as given).

Comment: Yes, as i didn't understood the error also didn't notice that. Now it is correct, I think. Thanks @moewe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `^` and some other characters have a special meaning in Latex. To print these special characters in your text, you need to precede them with a backslash (i.e. `\^`). In math-mode, you can use it directly to rise a variable to power of something like the case in your code. When you add it inside the text-mode `(\textrm{B^-})` without using an escape character, it yields an error. So, to obtain the desired output, you need to move it outside the text-mode like `(\textrm{B}^-)`.